# How can I pass the DOM event as an event handler bind method

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, dom-events, bind

```
nav.addEventListener('mouseover',handleHover.bind(null,e,0.5))
```

I want to passing event itself as an argument to bind method but it gives an error. e is undefined. How can I pass the event itself into an event handler bind method?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? Just don't pass the second and third parameter of the `bind` so that the event is effectively passed as first parameter of `handleHover`

Comment: I have to set it's this to null and send event itself with 0.5 value to handleHover function. handleHover needs them for determining e.target and applying 0.5 value to e.target's opacity value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments:

```js
const handleHover = (event, opacity) => { 
  event.target.style.opacity = opacity; 
}

nav.addEventListener('mouseover', () => handleHover(event, 0.5));
```

```html
<div id="nav">Mouse Over</div>
```

Using `bind` (**Not Recommended**, just for clarification):

```js
const handleHover = () => { 
  event.target.style.opacity = opacity; 
}

nav.addEventListener('mouseover', handleHover.bind(event, opacity=0.5));
```

```html
<div id="nav">Mouse Over</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need event itself and 0.5 value. Not just the event itself

Comment: @utkuonursahin is there a reason that you're using ``bind`` instead of passing arguments?

Comment: First of all it's an event handler so if I want to pass some arguments I have to use bind method, at least as far as I know. Secondly I want to pass some arguments to that function because I want to play with float value so 0.5. I mean it's now 0.5 but I might want to use this function with 0.3 value in the future so I want it dynamic. And I need event itself because I am applying float value to e.target's opacity.

Comment: @utkuonursahin no not necessarily, I think passing arguments is good as shown in the above edit.

Comment: Yes, now it's okay. But I am wondering, is it possible to doing this like I said? So, passing event itself as a bind argument with some other values.

Comment: @utkuonursahin yes I edited, the answer. But I recommend passing arguments. ``bind`` is not used for such cases.